# Poner una imagen de manera responsive en un carousel con boostrap en vuejs

Tags: css, responsive, bootstrap

El problema surge cuando uso una imagen que tengo dentro de mi proyecto de manera local se muestra en toda la pantalla y no adopta el tamaño que tengo predeterminado para el corousel, mientas que si uso una de picsum no tienen problema alguno y se muestra de acuerdo al tamaño que le doy, uso la libreria de boostrap-vue (https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/carousel#carousel)
Asi es como se esta viendo y la imagen de abajo es el tamaño predeterminado
[image: Asi es como se ve]

[image: Como deberia verse]

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>
  <div class="container my-4">
    <b-carousel
      id="carousel-1"
      :interval="4000"
      controls
      indicators
      background="#2d4e74"
      img-width="1024"
      img-height="480"
    >
      <b-carousel-slide
        img-src="https://picsum.photos/1024/480/?image=52"
      ></b-carousel-slide>

      <b-carousel-slide>
        <template #img>
          <img
            class="d-block img-fluid w-100"
            width="1024"
            height="480"
            src="https://picsum.photos/2048/960/?image=12"
            alt="image slot"
          />
        </template>
      </b-carousel-slide>

      <b-carousel-slide>
        <template #img>
          <img
            class="d-block img-fluid w-100"
            height="1024"
            width="480"
            :src="require(`../assets/img/nodejs.svg`)"
          />
        </template>
      </b-carousel-slide>
    </b-carousel>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Te refieres a la imagen `nodejs.svg`? Que browser usas para verificar?

Comment: Si esa, ni importa si es png o svg simplemente no las pone del tamaño que deseo y uso chrome para verificar

Comment: Puedes agregar una captura de como se ve con la imagen externa y como se ve con la local? Puedes intentar hacienda una referencia estatica? (ej: `src="/assets/img/node.svg"`)

Comment: Ya trate de ponerlo como me recomendaste y simplemente no muestra la imagen